# differentiating between the usages of the word"learnt"

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

- They are learned people
- They are learnt people
- They are educated people

I am wondering if they are correct or mean the same?

I am also wondering if the following could be correct grammatically and semantically? Or, do they mean the same thing?

A. x is learnt that x should be careful...

B. x should be careful is learnt by someone...

Comment: I made that question there by a mistake, but I am wondering how to delete that one!!!

Comment: Thanks. I edited it comprehensively, and changed it with another question.

Comment: Nima, you shouldn't edit questions to ask *more* especially if they have been ansered. One reason is that future readers eill look at the answers  from *before* the edit and feel that they are bad answers because they are incomplete.

Comment: And you'll find more about the uses of learn**t** [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/learnt-vs-learned) and [here](http://grammarist.com/spelling/learned-learnt/). In short: *not using it* is an option, too....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Learned" is both a verb form (I learned, I have learned) and an adjective (I am a learned man). They are pronounced differently, however: the "e" is silent in the verb form, but pronounced in the adjective form. The adjective has the same meaning as educated, but it is slightly more pretentious. As for "learnt," it can be used as the past tense of "learn," but not as the adjective. I think it is disappearing from common usage, however.

Of your sentences, then, the second one is wrong. The first and third are correct and mean almost the same thing, the first being slightly more pretentious.

Comment: Thanks. However, I need a more accurate reply as to what I am concerned about it.

Comment: The second one is wrong. The first and third are correct and mean almost the same thing, the first being slightly more pretentious. And I think what you're asking for is a more specific answer, not a more accurate one.

Comment: My understanding is that _learnt_ as a past tense is still alive and well in BrE.

Comment: So, is merely the second one incorrect?